# PhoneGap Android Market Publishing

Tags: javascript, html, css, phonegap-build, phonegap-developer-app

Hi I'm looking for a good phoneGap tutorial all the way tru publishing an app, I've seen several but none have been able to help me successfully publish my apps.
I currently write on Html CSS Javascript
Any tips will greatly be appreciated thank you!!
I mostly get how to use phoneGap to where you make the folder with the "www" folder inside now after that when I try to insert my html into there and go tru the adobe phoneGap build it does build butttttttt when I make it into an Apk file and try to upload it to the market it gives the error that needs debugging and can't upload it to android. And that's where I am stuck....

```
<!doc type>
<html>
<head>simple html game</head>
<body>Simple html game for android market!</body>
<footer> any tips please submit thank you</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer all I needed to do is make it from debug able to signed so it can be published to the market and booooom to the store.